# Combining connect data into one file

Tags: php, pdo

I have a PHP file that I use to include when I connect to my db. It looks something like this:

```
<?php

$mysqlhst = "localhost";
$database = "mydb1";
$username = "my_usr";
$password = "mypas2db1";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysqlhst;dbname=$database;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

I also have a second database that I frequently access at the same time as the first one. Can I combine both connections like this or is there a better way of doing it?

```
<?php

$mysqlhst = "localhost";
$database = "mydb1";
$username = "my_usr1";
$password = "mypas2db1";

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysqlhst;dbname=$database;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }

$database = "mydb2";
$username = "my_usr2";
$password = "mypas2db2";

try {
    $db2 = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysqlhst;dbname=$database;charset=UTF8", $username, $password);
    $db2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
?>
```

Comment: You can make a method that returns you a PDO object.

Comment: Sounds great, but I'm not sure what exactly do you mean.

Comment: Do you use any framework or is it just core PHP?

Comment: Make a DB class and you can reuse all your code in instances.

Comment: Most of my pages rely on some form of data from db. I usually add something like include_once: db_connect.php; Trying to stay away from frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not using Classes, you could DRY (Do-not Repeat Yourself) up your code a little like the following. This allows for extending into even further databases/users/servers in the future if required:

```
<?php

$connections = [
    'db1' => [
        'host' = 'localhost';
        'database' = 'mydb1';
        'username' = 'my_usr1';
        'password' = 'mypas2db1';
    ],
    'db2' => [
        'host' = 'localhost';
        'database' = 'mydb2';
        'username' = 'my_usr2';
        'password' = 'mypas2db2';
    ],
];

function getDatabaseConnection($connectionName = 'db1'): ?PDO
{
    global $connections;
    if (empty($connections[$connectionName]) {
        // Throw an exception because this connection doesn't exist.
        throw new \Exception(
            "Connection: {$connectionName} not specified."
        );
    }

    $data = $connections[$connectionName];
    $dbHost = $data['host'] ?: 'localhost';
    $dbUsername = $data['username'] ?: '';
    $dbPassword = $data['password'] ?: '';
    $dbName = $data['database'] ?: '';

    if (!$dbUsername || !$dbName) {
        // We don't have a username or database to connect to. Fail.
        throw new \Exception(
            'No valid database name or user provided.'
        );
    }


    $db = new PDO(
        "mysql:host={$dbHost};dbname={$dbName};charset=UTF8",
        $dbUsername,
        $dbPassword
    );
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    return $db;
}

// We don't need to specify a connection because we want the default, db1.
$db1 = getDatabaseConnection();

// Specify we want a connection to db2.
$db2 = getDatabaseConnection('db2');
```

Comment: I fixed your code a bit because failing silently considered a bad practice. We all want to know why the database connection didn't work :)

Comment: You're right I agree. That was a bad copy/paste. Ideally, we should instead remove the try/catch altogether, and just let the PDOException bubble up, rather than re-throwing the same thing. I'll edit.

Comment: Isn't PDO a PHP class already and if yes, shouldn't we extend it?

Comment: You could extend the class. But I don't see much value in doing so, unless you're intending on overriding the default behaviour. The function is type-hinted to return an instance of `\PDO` as your question simply asks "is there a better way of doing it?".